# Selenium WebDriver tests with JavaScript disabled

Tags: javascript, firefox, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

One of our internal applications (written in *angularjs*) has a special error box appearing if javascript is disabled in the browser (using [`noscript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fnoscript)), similar to the one on stackoverflow:

[image]
I'm trying to write an automated test for it, but having difficulties.

We are using `protractor`, but I'm pretty sure this is not about it. Here is the protractor configuration file:

```
'use strict';

var helper = require('./helper.js');

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001',

    capabilities: helper.getFirefoxProfile(),

    framework: 'jasmine',
    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true
    }
};
```

where `helper.js` is:

```
var q = require('q');
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');

exports.getFirefoxProfile = function() {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
    firefoxProfile.encoded(function(encodedProfile) {
        var capabilities = {
            'browserName': 'firefox',
            'firefox_profile' : encodedProfile,
            'specs': [
                '*.spec.js'
            ]
        };
        deferred.resolve(capabilities);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

As you see, we are setting `javascript.enabled` firefox preference to `false` which has been proven to work if you manually open up `about:config` in firefox, change it to `false` - you would see the contents of `noscript` section.

But, when I run the tests, I am getting the following error:

> Exception thrown org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: waiting for
>   evaluate.js load failed

Here is the [complete traceback](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/8247dd77d55ea34c8916).

FYI, selenium `2.44.0` and firefox `33.1.1` are used.

As far as I understand (with the help of several points raised [here](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/08/disable-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver/)), **disabling javascript is killing the javascript webdriver itself**. Is it true? If yes, what are my options or workarounds?

---

Notes:

- in case of chrome, in the past it was possible to disable javascript via [`--disable-javascript` command-line argument](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-javascript), but [not](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3175) [anymore.](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6672)
- this leads to a workaround number 0 - downgrade chrome to an old version which supported the command-line flag - this would be a not-tested plan B
- setting `javascript.enabled=false` firefox preference works with *python selenium bindings*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
  profile.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False)
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

  driver.get('https://my_internal_url.com')
  # no errors and I can assert the error is present
  ```

<sup>I'm open to any suggestions and can provide you with any additional information.</sup>

Comment: The fact that you can turn off JavaScript and still have the Python code work suggests to me that turning off JavaScript is not killing the part of WebDriver that lives inside the browser. Most likely the errors you are getting with JavaScript disabled are due to Protractor itself or WebDriverJS.

Comment: @Louis I don't know how are you doing this, but you've managed to help me again, your comment made me think deeply and triggered to dig into the source code. See the answer please. Thanks.

Comment: Just deductive reasoning, and lots and lots of time spent with Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what actually happened.

As it turns out, after exploring the source code of `protractor` and selenium js webdriver, the key problem is not in the js webdriver or `protractor`, it was in the way my test was written.

There is a setting called [`ignoreSynchronization`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/0bbfd2b6d38392938781d846ad37b5a0fd964004/lib/protractor.js#L1057-L1066) which by default is `false`:

```
  /**
   * If true, Protractor will not attempt to synchronize with the page before
   * performing actions. This can be harmful because Protractor will not wait
   * until $timeouts and $http calls have been processed, which can cause
   * tests to become flaky. This should be used only when necessary, such as
   * when a page continuously polls an API using $timeout.
   *
   * @type {boolean}
   */
  this.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

And I was not setting it to `true` which made `protractor` to try synchronizing with the page and execute client side scripts, which [`evaluate.js`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/firefox-driver/js/evaluate.js) is responsible for.

The solution was so simple I could not imagine - just setting `ignoreSynchronization` to `true` solved the problem:

```
'use strict';

require('jasmine-expect');

describe('Disabled Javascript', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('index.html');
    });

    it('should show disabled js', function () {
        var element = browser.findElement(by.tagName('noscript'));
        expect(element.getText()).toEqual('Please enable Javascript and try again.');
    });
});
```

Hope this would help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand (with the help of several points raised here), disabling javascript is killing the javascript webdriver itself. Is it true?

Yes. Note that WebDriver itself runs as a Firefox extension, so its code isn't affected by you disabling JavaScript. However, the error message indicates that Selenium is attempting to run some code in the context of the webpage. For that it injects a `<script>` tag into the webpage and puts the contents of `evaluate.js` into it. Then it waits for that script to set a flag indicating that it is ready - something that never happens of course because scripts aren't running in that webpage.

> If yes, what are my options or workarounds?

The important question is what Selenium is trying to run there. Your traceback is merely indicating that some code is calling `executeScript()` or `executeAsyncScript()`. I couldn't find any implied calls to either method in the Selenium codebase (at least not in any files related to Firefox web driver). Given that Selenium is open source, you should be able to debug it and add a breakpoint on `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript()` and `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeAsyncScript()` - that way you will actually see the script being executed there. Alternatively, you can also recompile `RemoteWebDriver.java` and make it produce debugging output.

Looking into how these methods are implemented, there might also be another way: telling Selenium that JavaScript is disabled. This should work via capabilities:

```
'javascriptEnabled': false,
```

According to documentation this capability only works on HTMLUnitDriver, yet Selenium will always consider it and from the source code specifying it for Firefox seems possible. With this capability any calls executing scripts on web pages will fail early.

Answer (score 0):

as per your stacktrace, it seems you are using ff 33.1 with selenium 2.43.1, so it wont support. Please upgrade your selenium version to 2.44 to enable tests on ff-33.

Comment: That could be a problem, but updated selenium to `2.44.0` - the issue persists (updated the traceback). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative solution/workaround - ["NoScript Security Suite" firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/noscript/).

It disables javascript per-domain and, by default, it does it for all sites except listed in the whitelist. This makes the webdriver run without problems, open up a web page, then the extension disables javascript for this particular site and I see the contents of the `noscript` tag.

Here's the protractor config:

```
'use strict';

var helper = require('./disabledJavascript.helper.js');

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    capabilities: helper.getFirefoxProfile(),
    chromeOnly: false,

    specs: [
        'disabledJavascript.spec.js'
    ],

    framework: 'jasmine',

    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true
    }
};
```

where `disabledJavascript.helper.js` contains:

```
'use strict';

var q = require('q');
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');

exports.getFirefoxProfile = function() {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    firefoxProfile.addExtension('./test/e2e/disabledJavascript/noscript.xpi', function () {
        firefoxProfile.encoded(function(encodedProfile) {
            var capabilities = {
                'firefox_profile' : encodedProfile,
                'browserName': 'firefox'
            };
            deferred.resolve(capabilities);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

where `noscript.xpi` is a downloaded "Noscript" extension.

Comment: This solution seems to negate the point of testing given that having NoScript extension installed isn't the same thing as having JavaScript disabled. The behavioral differences are indeed quite significant. You didn't reply to my suggestions, I guess that the `javascriptEnabled` capability didn't work?

Comment: @WladimirPalant I agree that there might be a difference in how javascript is disabled, you may think of more as a workaround than a real solution - though no other options worked - I had no luck setting `javascriptEnabled` preference, also played around with `--disable-javascript` chrome option and old chrome browser versions. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you could still debug Selenium - that's not something I can do for you ;)

Comment: @WladimirPalant I'm afraid of what I would find there :) (the proof that disabling js affects the run of webdriver startup scripts) Anyway, I am going to award a bounty to you for the participation and multiple options.

Comment: @WladimirPalant ok, I've followed your advice and explored the source code - problem solved :) `Read the source, Luke` - you should have said :)