# Disable JavaScript in Chrome with rendered page with C# & Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, selenium

I am running my test in Visual Studio 10, with C# and Selenium. There is a moment that Im landing on a page and I need to check some elements of the page, but its like "loading" continuously so its impossible to find this elements, cause are changing. The only way to find them is in Chrome Settings, Disable JavaScript and perfect it works. But how I disable Javascript with selenium in the same page, without call a new one? Just refreshing or smthg. Thx!!!

ElBandido

Comment: The page doesn't stop loading - so that's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can set that to profiler. Handling would be different based on how you want to do it

```
var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099250/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-with-javascript-disabled)

**For Chrome**

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-javascript"));
```

Taken from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3175)

Comment: Saifur thanks for your reply, but I said in Chrome, I was googling for few hours before ask, no see any way to do it in Chrome once opened the browser. Thanks anyway!

Comment: He asked for it to be in C# not JS

Comment: @LukeRayner not sure what you meant. My code is In Java But, this can easily be converted to any language