# How can I enable javascript in Internet explorer with Webdriver code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can we enable java script in Internet explorer, safari and chrome with webdriver, does this browser respond to java script calls and do we really have any way?

If we have,

a. Does it really working

b. Can we set any capability before launching the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this doc](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Safari_specific). Large part of these drivers are written using `javaScript` so far I know. Disabling `JavaScript` may have some REAL bad consequences. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099250/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-with-javascript-disabled) discussion. This is one of my favorite.

However, if you know for sure what are you doing then `DesiredCapabilities` is the way to go for enabling and disabling the capabilities of drivers.