# C# - How can I disable javascript in firefox with selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using below code to disable java script in C# Selenium webdriver with specflow.

```
FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile();
p.SetPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);
```

I am not able disable javascript for firefox browser.
Can you please help me where I am wrong.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple suggestions to use `FirefoxProfile` or `DesireCapabilities` to accomplish that. Those also never work for me. What did is the answer from a brilliant SO user @alecxe. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099250/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-with-javascript-disabled)

Luckily, there are people who do some great work for us so we can take the benefit. Use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/noscript/) add-on and that will solve your problem. And configuring that is real simple. Just *right click* on the **Add to Firefox** button and *Save link as* that will give you the option to save the `.xpi`. Then, configure the the `Firefox` profiler as follows.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AddExtension(@"D:\Users\Saifur\Desktop\noScript.xpi");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

And, just to show you it's working I did a [Scrrencast](http://screencast.com/t/BYYIyDoh)

Comment: Thanks Saifur. It worked for me.. Can you please help to perform same for google Chrome?

Comment: @user3207067 Will take a look after work. Not on top of my head right now