# JS off with "profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)" for firefox(v35) doesn't work for selenium 47 and above. Is there any other way?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, firefox-os

Doesn't work:

```
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False);
```

It throws below error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>    Preference javascript.enabled may not be overridden: frozen value=true, requested value=false

With selenium 46 and below I could disable javascript with the above one liner code. It just Selenium version 47 and above where it is not working. Therefore I'd like to know if there is any other method with which i can disable javascript from code only.

The solution given in other post [C# - How can I disable javascript in firefox with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146738/c-sharp-how-can-i-disable-javascript-in-firefox-with-selenium) does not suffice my need as with that plugin mentioned (NoScript.xpi), FF would launched in javascript off mode always. And as a reason, my jaavscript specific automation script won't work.

Comment: It means you cant. It's firefox or firefox-os?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix it is firefox browser, I've added more details to description.
Thanks.