# selenium chromedriver taking much time to complete loading of a website

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to use the selenium chromedriver browser for scrapping purposes and I found that the page gets the info I want and it is still loading. I don't wait all this time so is there a function to stop loading the page and complete the rest of the code ?

```
        ChromeDriver CD = new ChromeDriver();

        CD.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
        //Complete the code after two seconds from calling the Navigate function 
        //and stop the loading process of the selenium browser
        CD.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"signup-form\"]/div[6]").Click();
```

I tried using this code but it crashes the program I want the program to complete without timeout of the selenium browser.

```
        CD.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: **it crashes the program** - Did you get any exception on this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not selenium, its simply website is slow. If you want to scrap website take a look to bots, since when selenium is loading it will load all assets such as images, css, js and so on.

[Abot](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot) for instance can be configured to load only html. Which is way faster.

Comment: I am using the js ,but what I mean that the info I need is loaded after two seconds of website loading start and the website takes more time to load more info that I don't need so I want it to stop loading after two seconds.

Comment: @YupatshiMakni i think that Selenium has event on document ready and only after that it kick in..

Answer (score 0):

If the data you need is in the html document before JS loads, and assuming JS is the part that is taking a long time to load, you should be able to speed up the loading time by disabling javascript, which can be accomplished using browser profiles.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29160289/2386700

It really depends on what is causing the slow load. If it's because of CSS or images, etc, you may be able to skip those using a similar approach.

Browser profiles allow you to use browser extensions. Extensions can execute their code both before and after the document loads. That's how they can change how it loads.

Not sure if there are already extensions for CSS/images as well. But you could always create one.

If the slowness is simply due to the response time of the server itself, then there's not much you can do with Selenium to help that.