# Use existing Firefox profile with disabled JavaScript, in C# Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, firefox, profile

I am trying to use an existing Firefox profile, that I created, and in which I went to about:config and set javascript.enabled to false manually.

```
var profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
FirefoxProfile fxProfile = profileManager.GetProfile("nojs");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fxProfile);
```

But when the driver starts, JavaScript is still being enabled.

Any suggestions, please!

Comment: Disabling JS via `javascript.enabled` no longer works, use an extension (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769915/disabling-javascript-when-using-capybara-selenium/39301760#39301760).

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question wasn't though about Disabling JS via javascript.enabled with automation. But disabling it manually and then loading saved profile. That's why I opened a separate topic.

Comment: Ah, okay, I've reopened the question, sorry. Thanks.